# Laravel - I can't log user in

Tags: php, laravel

Fairly new to Laravel, following a tutorial for multi user authentication. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55YoSeS6egs)

Everything has gone fairly smoothly but for some reason my admin (restaurantuser) isn't logging in. It literally just refreshes the page without any errors. I've compared repositories and i can't find any errors.

I think its a version mismatch coding error. I'll provide all relevant code and hopefully someone can help me out.

form login html

```
<div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('restaurantuser.login.submit') }}">
                    @csrf

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                            @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                            @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                    {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                {{ __('Login') }}
                            </button>

                            @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                    {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                </a>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

web

```
    Route::prefix('restaurantuser')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\RestaurantUserLoginController@showLoginForm')->name('restaurantuser.login');
    Route::post('/login', 'Auth\RestaurantUserLoginController@login')->name('restaurantuser.login.submit');
    Route::get('/', 'RestaurantUserController@index')->name('restaurantuser.dashboard');
    Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\RestaurantUserLoginController@logout')->name('restaurantuser.logout');
});
```

restaurant user log in controller

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    // Validate the form data
  $this->validate($request, [
    'email'   => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required|min:6'
  ]);

  // Attempt to log the user in
  if (Auth::guard('restaurantuser')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password], $request->remember)) {
    // if successful, then redirect to their intended location
    return redirect()->intended(route('restaurantuser.dashboard'));
  }

  // if unsuccessful, then redirect back to the login with the form data
  return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));

}
```

dd on request:

```
Request {#43 ▼
#json: null
#convertedFiles: null
#userResolver: Closure($guard = null) {#183 ▶}
#routeResolver: Closure() {#185 ▶}
+attributes: ParameterBag {#45 ▶}
+request: ParameterBag {#44 ▶}
+query: ParameterBag {#51 ▶}
+server: ServerBag {#47 ▶}
+files: FileBag {#48 ▶}
+cookies: ParameterBag {#46 ▶}
+headers: HeaderBag {#49 ▶}
#content: null
#languages: null
#charsets: null
#encodings: null
#acceptableContentTypes: null
#pathInfo: "/restaurantuser/login"
#requestUri: "/assignment2/public/restaurantuser/login"
#baseUrl: "/assignment2/public"
#basePath: null
#method: "POST"
#format: null
#session: Store {#220 ▶}
#locale: null
#defaultLocale: "en"
-isHostValid: true
-isForwardedValid: true
basePath: "/assignment2/public"
format: "html"
```

if any more code is required, let me know and ill update it immediately. This is for a school project so any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the form?

Comment: sure,  i just edited it.

Comment: put dd($request) inside the login function in the first line of function just to check whether request is okay or not. 
please post the result.

Comment: okay, i edited and posted it above.

Comment: @patrickGold, have you set up guard `restaurantuser` in config/auth.php?
also can you post error that you got?

Comment: Yes i have set up the guard in auth.php. I can post it if needed. Also I haven't gotten any errors, the page is just refreshing upon logging in.

Comment: @patrickGold, can you `echo` or `dd` before redirect and check in which condition it is going

Comment: Upon using dd, its passing through the unsuccessful condition. Which makes sense as to why it's only refreshing the page. Any idea as to why its not passing through the successful condition?

Comment: I think you should give me the output of dd($request->request) instead of just dd($request) bcoz I need to see parameters is okay or not? @patrickGold

Comment: ParameterBag {#44 ▼
  #parameters: array:3 [▼
    "_token" => "QHjpmpVEDS19LrW3iayjgVgmfe2fbNp7xI6iaaH1"
    "email" => "admin@test.com"
    "password" => "adminadmin"
  ]
}

Comment: okay, your request seems OK. now can I get the output of currently logged in user by putting dd(Auth::user()); inside first condition just above the line "return redirect()->intended(route('restaurantuser.dashboard'));" make sure comment out other dd() function.

Comment: null after using dd(Auth::user());

Comment: that means your user is not getting login or you may don't have admin user created inside database

Comment: DB::table('restaurantuser')->insert([
            'name' => "admin",
            'email' => 'admin@test.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('adminadmin'),
            ]);

This is the seeder i'm using for restaurantuser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200087/discussion-between-imzedi-and-patrickgold).